# How can I stop the blinking when rotating a Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d

I wrote a function `interactiveDesign` that returns different `Graphics3D` items in a list. Then I call the function `interactiveDesign`, create a textured part (`add`), and show everything in one plot.

```
interactiveDesign[innerColors_,outerColors_,width_,length_,wallsHeight_,middleHeight_,viewPoint_,click_,procedureButton_]:=
                  (lines={};
                   For[i=1,i<= Round[((N[length/10])-1)],i++,(lines=Append[lines,Polygon[{{0,((10*i)-0.5),wallsHeight},{(width/2),((10*i)-0.5),middleHeight},{(width/2),(10*i),middleHeight},{0,(10*i),wallsHeight}}]])];
                   lines1={};
                   For[i=1,i<= Round[((N[length/10])-1)],i++,(lines1=Append[lines1,Polygon[{{width,((10*i)-0.5),wallsHeight},{(width/2),((10*i)-0.5),middleHeight},{(width/2),(10*i),middleHeight},{width,(10*i),wallsHeight}}]])];
                   gridLines1=Graphics3D[{LightBlue,lines},RotationAction->"Clip",Lighting->{innerColors},ViewPoint->viewPoint,Boxed-> False];
                   gridLines2=Graphics3D[{LightBlue,lines1},RotationAction->"Clip",Lighting->{innerColors},ViewPoint->viewPoint,Boxed-> False];
                   rightWall=Graphics3D[{innerColors,Polygon[{{0,0,0},{0,0,wallsHeight},{0,length,wallsHeight},{0,length,0}}]},Boxed-> False,Lighting->{{"Ambient",innerColors}},RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint-> viewPoint];
                   leftWall=Graphics3D[{innerColors,Polygon[{{width,0,0},{width,0,wallsHeight},{width,length,wallsHeight},{width,length,0}}]},Boxed-> False,Lighting->{{"Ambient",innerColors}},RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint-> viewPoint];
                   backWall=Graphics3D[{innerColors,Polygon[{{0,length,0},{0,length,wallsHeight},{N[width/2],length,middleHeight},{width,length,wallsHeight},{width,length,0}}]},Boxed-> False,Lighting->{{"Ambient",innerColors}},RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint-> viewPoint];
                   shad1=Graphics3D[{outerColors,Polygon[{{0,0,wallsHeight},{N[width/2],0,middleHeight},{N[width/2],length,middleHeight},{0,length,wallsHeight}}]},Boxed-> False ,Lighting->{{"Ambient",outerColors}},RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint-> viewPoint];
                  shad2=Graphics3D[{outerColors,Polygon[{{width,0,wallsHeight},{N[width/2],0,middleHeight},{N[width/2],length,middleHeight},{width,length,wallsHeight}}]},Boxed-> False,Lighting->{{"Ambient",outerColors}},RotationAction->"Clip" ,ViewPoint-> viewPoint];
                  floor=Graphics3D[{LightBlue,Polygon[{{0,0,0},{0,length,0},{width,length,0},{width,0,0}}]},Boxed-> False,Lighting->{{"Ambient",LightBlue}},RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint-> viewPoint ];
                  frontDoom=Graphics3D[{outerColors,Polygon[{{0,0,wallsHeight},{N[width/2],0,middleHeight},{width,0,wallsHeight}}]},Boxed-> False,Lighting->{{"Ambient",outerColors}},RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint-> viewPoint];
                  frontEnd1=Graphics3D[{outerColors,Polygon[{{0,0,0},{0,0,wallsHeight},{N[width/4],0,wallsHeight},{N[width/4],0,0}}]},Boxed-> False ,Lighting->{{"Ambient",outerColors}},RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint-> viewPoint];
                  frontEnd2=Graphics3D[{outerColors,Polygon[{{N[(width-(width/4))],0,0},{N[(width-(width/4))],0,wallsHeight},{width,0,wallsHeight},{width,0,0}}]},Boxed-> False,Lighting->{{"Ambient",outerColors}},RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint-> viewPoint];
                  {gridLines1,gridLines2,rightWall,leftWall,backWall,shad1,shad2,floor,frontDoom,frontEnd1,frontEnd2});

 parts = interactiveDesign[LightGreen, Gray, 500, 300, 300, 400, {2, -2, 0}, 1, ""];

 add = {Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Gray], Gray,Texture[Style["Subbu", Bold, 25]], Opacity[1], 
                   Polygon[
 Inner[Plus, {{30, 0, 10}, {100, 0, 10}, {100, 0, 70}, {30, 0, 70}}, {-5, -5, 0},List], 
              VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
      ]}, 
                  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {Gray}, RotationAction -> "Clip"
                 ]};

  Show[parts, add]
```

[image]

Everything is fine but the item with `Texture`(`add`) is blinking whenever the `Graphics3D` is rotated. How can I prevent this blinking during rotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Subbu,

I specifically tested your code on two computers. One with a proper graphics card and other without one. There is no blinking when the code is run on the computer with a graphics card. However, the problems returns when there code is run on the computer without graphics card.

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Anu

Answer (score 16):

The issue has nothing to do with `Texture`. It is because the polygon you define in `add` is at the same plane where the front wall is: if you only use e.g. a red polygon instead of a textured one, you still would see the blinking feature, as *Mathematica* fails to decide which polygon to draw before the other: the wall or the red one (known as [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)). So you can simply move the smaller one a bit out of the wall, like this:

```
Polygon[
     Inner[Plus, {{30, 0, 10}, {100, 0, 10}, {100, 0, 70}, {30, 0, 70}}, {-5, -5, 0}, List], 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
]
```

Comment: :Thank you for your reply...

Comment: ,your answer is working great,but at the rotation time,`Texture`is not visible clearely...                  How can we solve that?

Comment: @subbu Sorry, I don't get it. If I put together everything, I can see the texture clearly during rotation.

Comment: @ István Zachar,I am using mathematica 9.0,I evaluated your code with my code.during rotation time `Texture` is not visible clearly. By this, I mean to say if I have a text block and some letters in the text block, during rotation, the letters disappear. It happens even if I place some images which are required to be seen even during rotation. They appear after I stop the rotation.

Comment: @subbu At my end (Win), everything seems fine. What machine/graphics hardware do you use? Could you further specify the issue in your post so that others could join in the quest, as at the moment I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: No problems here, either. @subbu: try updating your display driver.

Answer (score 3):

Your code, with István's fix, works fine (v9.0.0, Mac OS 10.6).  Here's another way: punch a hole in the wall where the textured rectangle appears.

The following definition puts a rectangular hole in a rectangular polygon.  It divides the polygon into 9 rectangles (3 x 3) and drops the middle one.  The code messes up `EdgeForm` so an optional argument to `rectWithHole3D` can specify the edge style; beware, it will inherit from the current `Line` style, too.  I suspect there may be more efficient and general ways of doing this.

```
rectToPoly[{LL_, UR_}] := Tuples[Transpose@{LL, UR}][[{1, 3, 4, 2}]];
insertFixed[poly2d_, fixedCoord_, fixedPart_] := Insert[#, fixedCoord, fixedPart] & /@ poly2d;
rectWithHole3D[pts_List, hole_List, edgeForm_: None] := 
  With[{fixedPart = Position[SameQ @@@ Transpose[pts], True][[1, 1]]},
    With[{fixedCoord = pts[[1, fixedPart]],
     corners = Drop[Flatten[Table[{{i, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}], 1], {5}], (* Drop {5} = center *)
     newvertices = 
      Outer[List, Sequence @@ Transpose@Drop[(pts~Join~hole)[[{1, 5, 7, 3}]], None, {fixedPart}]]}, 
    {{EdgeForm[], Polygon@insertFixed[#, fixedCoord, fixedPart] &@
         rectToPoly@Extract[newvertices, #] & /@ corners}, 
     If[edgeForm =!= None, {edgeForm, Line[pts], Line[hole]}, {}]}
    ]
   ];
```

Then here are the changes to your code that need to be made.

```
addVertices = {{30, 0, 10}, {100, 0, 10}, {100, 0, 70}, {30, 0, 70}};
frontEnd1 = 
 Graphics3D[{outerColors, 
   rectWithHole3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, wallsHeight}, {N[width/4], 0, wallsHeight}, {N[width/4], 0, 0}},
    addVertices, Black]},
  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", outerColors}}, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
  ViewPoint -> viewPoint];

add = {Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Gray], Gray, 
    Texture[Style["Subbu", Bold, 25]], Opacity[1], 
    Polygon[addVertices, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
   Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {Gray}, RotationAction -> "Clip"]};
```

[image: Subbu's house]

You may not like that it changes your function `interactiveDesign`, so that it depends on the external size and position of `add` (managed here through the variable `addVertices`).  But it should solve the flickering problem and put the "Subbu" rectangle right where you want it.  (You can also add windows.)