# 3D graphics rendering artifact with overlapping planes (z-fighting)

Tags: graphics3d, rendering

I am trying to render a matrix as a depth map:

```
data = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 3, 1}, {2, 0, 0, 1}};
ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
           Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> {Opacity[1]}, 
           ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 5}]
```

[image: my depth map]

However, for the matrix element with the lowest value, the height of the corresponding bar in the plot is zero. This results in rendering artifacts (z-fighting).

Viewing the graph from below or rotating the graph makes the problem more obvious:

[image: see the artifacts]

Comment: I get a different issue, from some viewpoints I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8JZ5B.png), but from others I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4MSS.png)

Comment: Does `FillingStyle -> {Opacity[.9]}` help you any?

Comment: @JasonB In my understanding of the problem, the "lid" and "bottom" plane of the bar are positioned identicaly, resulting in them "fighting" to be displayed. The result changes depending on your view angle. I choose a specifically bad angle as an example. I will add an animation showing how it flickers depending on the angle.

Comment: @YvesKlett No. Same problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13967/how-can-i-stop-the-blinking-when-rotating-a-graphics3d). Since it is partly a graphics-card-related issue, that Q was closed as too localized. I do not agree with this, because it is also partly an overlapping-planes-related issue that is easily resolvable by code and no need to buy a bigger machine. Nonetheless, your example looks ok at my screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not entirely the same, as it changes coloring and z-scaling, but perhaps something similar may be of help. Essentially, the zero values are lifted by a small increment, while the original z-range is preserved.

```
data = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 3, 1}, {2, 0, 0, 1}};
ListPlot3D[data /. x_ /; x < .01 -> 0.01, Mesh -> None, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom, 
 FillingStyle -> {Opacity[1]}, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", 
 ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {Min[data], Max[data]}}]
```

**EDIT**

even better (shorter and broader applicability)  as proposed by the OP:

```
ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> {Opacity[1]}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {Min[data] - 0.01, Max[data]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could you change your solution to `ListPlot3D[data + 0.01, ...  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {Min[data], Max[data] + 0.01}}]` or something similar? Otherwise it will not work for datasets with `Min[data] != 0` or all zero values.

Comment: Event better: `ListPlot3D[data, ... PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {Min[data] - 0.01, Max[data]}}]`

Comment: Good suggestion! I added that unless you want to self-answer... (which you can still do anyway).

Answer (score 14):

In at least this case, `Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True}`, which is useful when you have nearly coplanar polygons in your plot, removes the observed jitter and streakiness. I picked this up [from Brett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6956991#6956991).

```
{ListPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", Filling -> Bottom, 
            FillingStyle -> {Opacity[1]}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> None,
            PlotLabel -> "Before", ViewPoint -> {-Pi, -Pi, -2}], 
 ListPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", Filling -> Bottom, 
            FillingStyle -> {Opacity[1]}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> None,
            Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True}, PlotLabel -> "After", 
            ViewPoint -> {-Pi, -Pi, -2}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: a comparison]

Comment: Oooh,  this sounds interesting...  just firing up my system to test on some old-time problem cases.

Comment: Huh,  no help for *my* coplanar artifacts (those remain belligerent as ever), but still good to knowl

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should post your stuff in a new question, @Yves. Sounds like a stiff challenge...

Answer (score 9):

In v10.1 under Windows x64 I experience no "z-fighting" in this example when using the `"BSPTree"` rendering method.  This method may be individually selected using [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle.html)

```
data = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 3, 1}, {2, 0, 0, 1}};
plot = ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom, 
  FillingStyle -> {Opacity[1]}, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", 
  ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 5}]

Show[plot,
 BaseStyle -> 
  RenderingOptions ->
   {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]
```

The same Option may be given in `ListPlot3D` but I separated it with `Show` for clarity.

It may also be set globally for a session with:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
  RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]
```

Or persistently by changing `$FrontEndSession` to `$FrontEnd` in the code above.

---

Other cases where the rendering method is important:

- [Unintended edge extensions in 3D Cube rendering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15735/121)
- [Opacity renders lines incorrect in certain viewing angles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65260/121)
- [Weird behaviour of multiple transparent Raster3D objects in one Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88520/121)

And one I just found which basically duplicates this question:

- [Possible Bug in ArrayMesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111945/121)