# Remove parasitic dashing from the cuboid face in a complex 3D image

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization

I am making a complex 3D image; part of it is a `Cuboid`, another part is a `DensityPlot3D`:

```
Show[{
  Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.5], FaceForm[Opacity[0.5]], 
     Cuboid[{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]}}, Boxed -> False],
  Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Directive[Blue]], Opacity[0.5], 
    Prism[{{-1, -0.1, 0}, {-1, 0.1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {-1, -0.1, 1}, {-1,
        0.1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}],
  DensityPlot3D[
   Exp[-6 r^2 + 1.5 Sqrt[r]*Cos[θ/2]]*
     Exp[-15 (z - 0.5)^2] /. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], θ -> 
      ArcTan[x + 0.001, y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> (If[# > 0, Red, Green] &)]

  }]
```

which looks like what follows:

[image: my figure]

As you see, the front face of the cuboid contains some dirt, some sort of a parasitic dashing. If I remove the `DensityPlot3D`, this dirt disappears:

```
Show[{
  Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.5], Cuboid[{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]}}, 
   Boxed -> False],
  Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Directive[Blue]], Opacity[0.5], 
    Prism[{{-1, -0.1, 0}, {-1, 0.1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {-1, -0.1, 1}, {-1,
        0.1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}]
  }]
```

[image: better image]

and we see a clear face. Thus, it is due to the `DensityPlot3D` that I get the parasitic image part.

Any idea on how to remove it?

Comment: Does this work for you: `Cuboid[1.001 {-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]`?

Comment: @ Kuba This removes the dirt from the front face, but creates one on the top and right faces.

Comment: Can't test more now but similar artifacts happen when there are overlapping polygons in 3d. So my idea was to shift something.

Comment: Can you try adding `Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True}` to `Show[]`?

Comment: @ J. M. Thank you, this works. Could you please formulate it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115792) is a possible dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
, Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True}
```

to `Show[]`.

[image]