# How to improve quality of this Plot3D

Tags: visualization

I tried driving up `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` but the intersections look weird, is there some other trick I can do?

```
plot = Plot3D @@ {Abs[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y]] /. {x -> Sin[2 x], 
     y -> Cos[2 y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, 
   MaxRecursion -> 6, Ticks -> None}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks fine to me, and I wonder what other plotting software would give a better image.  If you're using it in a paper, just render it large and scale down for the publication.

Comment: I tried a slightly different `ViewPoint` and the ridges disappeared.

Comment: related: [3D graphics rendering artifact with overlapping planes (z-fighting)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115792/125)

Comment: `NormalsFunction -> None` removes the glitches, and at such a high sampling density, the output looks pretty good.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it using `ListPlot3D`, and those effect go away

```
data=Table[ Abs[Sqrt[Sin[2 x]]+Sqrt[Cos[2 y]]],{x,-2,2,.005},{y,-2,2,.005}];
ListPlot3D[data,ImageSize->700,MeshFunctions->{#3&}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to your plot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems to be due to different sampling used by `Plot3D` vs. the manual method used in `ListPlot3D`. At least this can be a workaround until a better solution is found.

Answer (score 7):

The funny color the OP points out is the lighting effect that arises from a sharp-corner-like singularities in the surface. The discretization causes some polygons to bridge a sharp corner and reflect the light in a different way than its neighbor polygons. *Added:* In particular, the recursive subdivision algorithm of `Plot3D` causes adjacent polygons to have different angles.  Nasser's `ListPlot` approach has the same problem with bridging the corner, but it has a regular and very fine mesh aligned with the singularities: the mesh gives the singularities a regular appearance along their paths. The `ListPlot` approach also uses almost 50 times the memory than the method below on the OP's example.

It's too bad the `*Plot*` functions do not have a way of specifying and treating singular points as `NIntegrate` does.  For a plot with a tensor-product-like structure in the OP's post, all it would take is to specify the singular `x` values and singular `y` values to have the plot restart at these boundary points.

Here's a way to accomplish something like that by dividing the plot region into subrectangles.  `Plot3D` has a lot of automatic processing, and coordinating the subplots will require some tweaking.  For instance, the `Mesh` is computed based on the `PlotRange` of each subplot.  Therefore you have to manually specify `Mesh`. (One could make this automatic by computing the plot twice, once to determine the mesh range and specs, and again with the proper mesh specification.)

```
ClearAll[plot3D];
SetAttributes[plot3D, HoldAll];
plot3D[f_, {x_, x0__}, {y_, y0__}, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot3D]] :=
 Show[
  Plot3D[f, {x, #[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}, {y, #[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]}, opts] & /@
   Flatten[  (* Partition into rectangles *)
    Outer[List,
     Partition[SortBy[{x0}, N], 2, 1], 
     Partition[SortBy[{y0}, N], 2, 1],
     1],
    1],
  PlotRange -> (OptionValue[PlotRange] /. Automatic -> All)
  ]

(* compute the singular values of x and y *)
sing = With[{s = 
    Simplify`FunctionSingularities[
     Abs[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y]] /. {x -> Sin[2 x], y -> Cos[2 y]},
     {x, y}, {"ALL"}]},
  Merge[
   Cases[Flatten[
     Quiet@Simplify[
       Solve[# && -2 < x < 2 && -2 < y < 2, {x, y}, Reals] & /@ 
        Or @@@ Apply[And, s, {2}], -2 < x < 2 && -2 < y < 2]],
    sol : Verbatim[Rule][x | y, _] :> <|sol|>],
   Join]
  ]
(*  <|x -> {0, -(π/2), π/2}, y -> {-(π/4), π/4}|>  *)

(* plot the OP's graph *)
plot3D @@ {Abs[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y]] /. {x -> Sin[2 x], y -> Cos[2 y]}, 
  Flatten@{x, -2, sing[x], 2}, Flatten@{y, -2, sing[y], 2}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {Subdivide[0., 2., 15 + 1]}, 
  Ticks -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: With some work, this could probably be extended to curved singularities, provided it was computationally feasible.

Answer (score 4):

Increase the `MaxRecursion` and use the `WorkingPrecision` option

```
plot = Plot3D @@ {Abs[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y]] /. {x -> Sin[2 x], 
     y -> Cos[2 y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, MaxRecursion -> 8, 
   Ticks -> None, WorkingPrecision -> 15, ImageSize -> Large}
```

[image]