# Problem of color and solid mesh style of two surfaces in 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot two surfaces in the same figure using the following code.

```
meanr[t2_, t1_, kappa0_] := (Exp[-t1] - Exp[-t2]) kappa0
varr [t2_, t1_, 
  kappa0_] := ((t2 - t1) - 1 + Exp[-(t2 - t1)] - 
   0.5 (Exp[-t2] - Exp[-t1])^2)
orientCorrHeadTail[t_, T_, kappa0_, thetac_] := Exp[
   -0.5 thetac^2 varr[t, t - T, kappa0]] Cos[
   thetac meanr[t, t - T, kappa0]]
Plot3D[
 {orientCorrHeadTail[t, T, 0, 0.5], orientCorrHeadTail[t, T, 2, 0.5]},
 {t, 0, 10},
 {T, 0 , t},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"],
 Boxed -> False,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
 FaceGrids -> {{0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
 ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 60,
 ViewPoint -> {-0.9792377354119487`, 3.2154160743069498`, 
   0.39011911851862024`},
 ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

which generates the figure below
[image]

There are two problems in the above figure:

1. The yellow surface should be below the blue surface. There should not be yellow color dispersed in the red circle. Increase the PlotPoints option to 300 does not solve the problem;
2. The solid mesh on yellow surface near red arrow breaks. If the mesh style is changed to dashed or dotted, then it is OK. But solid mesh style is what I prefer.

How can I solve these two problems? Thanks for your time and consideration.

```
$Version
12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)
```

Comment: First problem looks like a classic example of what's called z-fighting, where a mesh intersects so closely that the renderer can't decide which texture to display.

Comment: For your first problem use `Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True}` in the plot option.

Comment: Mixing of the surfaces color is because the 2 surfaces are at this places identical. Simply add e.g. 10^-3 to one of the surfaces.

Comment: `BaseStyle -> 
 RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}` as plot option, solve both problems but is very slow and you should give up the interaction for your plot. (solution came from an answer by @Mr.Wizard in [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115792/3d-graphics-rendering-artifact-with-overlapping-planes-z-fighting/120419#120419))

Comment: Either `Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True}` or addition of a small number indeed solves the first problem. `BaseStyle ->   RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}` indeed solves both problems. Thank all you guys fro immediate and helpful responses. Really saved my day.